# Running RoboVM/libgdx iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, libgdx, robovm

I'm trying to develop an iOS app using RoboVM and libgdx. So far, I've just created a simple project, and have been trying to get it to run on iOS. So far, the farthest I've gotten is running this command:

```
robovm -verbose -arch x86 -os ios -cp robovm/lib/robovm-objc.jar:robovm/lib/robovm-cocoatouch.jar -jar <project>.jar
```

This generates a directory with a file called `Info.plist`, a file called `<package_name>.<main_class>`, and a lib directory. The file called `<package_name>.<main_class>` is a Mach-O executable i386. How would I go about running the file, and how would I go about uploading it to an iPhone as an app? There doesn't seem to be much documentation on RoboVM, and I've never really used a mac before, so I apologize if I'm missing something obvious.

Edit: To clarify, I want to both know how to run the app that was generated by RoboVM after I ran the command above, and to know how to upload that app to an iPhone to run it there. Preferably, I'd like to do this all without the RoboVM eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 5):

Did you use the [setup UI](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Project-setup,-running-&-debugging) of libgdx? If so you can easy run the project:

> [**iOS RoboVM:** Right click the robovm project, Run As -> iOS Device App to run on a connected device, or Run As -> iOS Simulator App to run on the iOS simulator. If you run on a device, you need to provision it to be able to deploy to it!   [Link about how to start developing with libgdx]](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Project-setup,-running-&-debugging)

Install roboVM plugin for eclipse. Create the Projects with the [setup UI](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Project-setup,-running-&-debugging). (Core and RoboVM) And rightclick the robo project **Run As -> iOS** and it should work.

You do not run it with commandline if you use libgdx. You are missing alot of lib and backend stuff from libgdx which need to be compiled too.

Moreover if you want to upload it to a device you need an [Provision](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/YourFirstAppStoreSubmission/ProvisionYourDevicesforDevelopment/ProvisionYourDevicesforDevelopment.html).

Comment: I'm using intellij and building with maven. I've created projects before using libgdx with this method and it's worked fine, I've just never tried exporting to iOS before.

The reason I'm using command line for the robovm part of the process is because I'm not using eclipse, and would prefer not to. The command I'm using seems to work fine, I'm just wondering what I'm supposed to do with the output file.

Comment: i think that the command line does not bind all needed librarys to the outputfile. I would just try out if eclipse gives you the same outputfiles. If not the commandline instruction does need some more parameters for the librarys.

Comment: I can't really try eclipse out that quickly, as the project relies on maven, and the eclipse robovm plugin doesn't seem to work with maven. While looking into this, I noticed there was a maven robovm plugin, which I tried using. However, I encountered an error with this that I detailed above.